# Should moderators be able to accept an answer which is clearly accepted by the questioner in a comment?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, bounty

About every third question I answer this happens to me:

The questioner is quite new to stackoverflow and clearly mentions my answer as the accepted one commenting to it. But they then never mark my answer as accepted. They either just made their account for this single question and never use it again, or they just don't know how SO works yet.

In situations like this, where there is clear proof that the questioner would have accepted your answer if s/he knew how stackoverflow works, I think it would be very useful if moderators could mark these answers as accepted and give a hint to the new/unexperienced users that they should have done this by themselves.

What do you think about this? And are there other possibilities how to deal with this problem?

Comment: No, they should not, because this is *not a problem that needs solving*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, for me and I guess for a lot of other SO users things like these are quite frustrating. and who wants SO to be frustrating?

Comment: easy solution: answer to help, not to get points. If your answer is truly helpful, votes over time will do the rest. And that whole 'marked as accepted' thing won't bother you so much either!

Comment: @TGMCians this is why I am talking about answer which have been clearly accepted by the questioner in a comment. and moderators can see the questioner's comment and decide if this counts as "accepting the answer".

Comment: You can always give a gentle nudge to teach the user that the feature exists, but as discussed on Meta.SE and here countless times before, no-one but the OP will ever be allowed to mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters then it's time for revolution to make SO a better place.

Comment: Marking an answer as accepted is a nicety, not a requirement. Even if the OP says 'thank you', it could be they are just being polite.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, i am talking about comments like this "Wow, you got it _username_. This is the answer. I appreciate your help."

Comment: cross-site related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149699/a-method-for-the-op-to-accept-comments

Comment: I know what you mean, but all you can do is remind them. I use: `Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)`.

Comment: better fitting cross-site related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18312/moderators-accepting-answers-on-users-behalf-after-a-certain-time-period

Comment: For what it's worth I've had answers accepted more than 1 year after posting them.

Comment: Also I often go back over my previous questions to see if I could accept an answer, or edit an answer to make it acceptable to me, or add in my own answer (adding relevant references etc). Although I admit that a new user may not do this ;)

Comment: No idea why this question has been downvoted so many times. Have an upvote, even if it doesn't help much at this point.

Answer (score 5):

**If I were a moderator, I would not want to have the power you are proposing.**

The reason is that I don't rely on other people's opinion to put my stamp of approval on something, **unless I have grounds to trust them.** What grounds would I have to trust that the user who left a comment saying "Thanks! It completely solved my problem!" is really correct? (And no, a high reputation is not enough. My experience on SO proves it.) As Martijn Pieters said, the user could have just been polite. Or the user could have jumped the gun, which happens often enough to be of concern. So is the moderator supposed to independently verify results before adding an acceptance mark? In some cases, that's no possible. In other cases, that's too much work. And then you'd have folks bugging moderators to flip the acceptance mark. As if they have nothing else to do...

What do you do then? Martijn Pieters suggested a gentle reminder. I agree. I usually put it something like this:

> It looks like this answer solved your problem. The best way to thank someone on SO who solved your problem is to accept and upvote their answer. Doing this benefits everyone: the person who helped you, the community, and you. The person who helped will get reputation. The community will know that the proposed solution was useful. The acceptance mark will also indicate that your problem is solved. You will appear to others as a good member of this community, besides getting +2 rep.

(If it is *my* answer, I'll probably open with "Glad to help!".)

Note that I put a comment like the above **only** if there is an indication **from the OP** that the answer solved the problem. I don't badger the OP, ever: I put the reminder once. I use such reminder for any answer that needs it, not just mine.

Comment: If the questioner left a comment saying "Thanks! It completely solved my problem!" then you wouldn't trust them, but if they used the proper 'Accept answer' feature then you would definitely trust them? I think this kind of moderator action is just as easy - maybe even easier - to judge than several other responsibilities they may have.